# My monetha tokens dissapeared from myetherwallet - please help!

Tags: myetherwallet

I recently bought Monetha(MTH) tokens and transferred them to my wallet (mytherwallet.com). Within few minutes i saw a transaction where in my tokens were transferred to another address.

Here is the transaction 0x5962a49c229d343814b77c6d6b929ef2c22de626711d5f10861eaf926793b77a

The address it was transferred to
0x9ee24f7ef4c6ff9c0b681af178d763d5eca70968

Is there anyway I can get them back?

Comment: It appear you have been using a scam wallet or your computer was compromised if that is the case you can report your case to https://etherscamdb.info/report/.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm really sorry, but it sounds like you may have been the victim of a phishing attack, likely from a DM via Slack or Reddit.

MyEtherWallet is a client-side wallet, which means you hold your keys. If someone gets your private key (keystore file, mnemonic, passwords), they have complete access to your funds. There is no stopping transactions, canceling transactions, or resetting passwords. Once a transaction is on the blockchain, it's final.

#### Report

1. Look through your history for any URLs that you accessed & entered your private key on. Typically, fake MyEtherWallet, EtherDelta, or similiar Ethereum-related sites.
2. Fill out the form here: https://etherscamdb.info/report/
3. Include your address, the URL you visited, and any additional information, including which Slack channels you were a part of or how you accessed the malicious link. Include a screenshot, if available, of the message sent. You can upload the screenshot to imgur and include it as a link with your add'l details.
4. Report to Google: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/ &
   https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/
5. If have IE / Edge, report there: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930167/how-to-report-a-phishing-web-site
6. Report any Google Adwords Campaigns here: https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/1190500?hl=en & https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/176378?hl=en
7. Find the abuse email of the host or registar & tell them to **stop hosting phishers who steal people's money!**. You can do this by searching the offending domain on whois: https://whois.icann.org/en or https://www.whois.com/ or https://whois.domaintools.com

#### Move your Funds ASAP & Protect Yourself Moving Forward

- [Install the EAL Chrome Extension that will warn you if you attempt to navigate to a malicious site](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/etheraddresslookup/pdknmigbbbhmllnmgdfalmedcmcefdfn) or... [Install the MetaMask Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn)
- Create new accounts, safely, and move any funds from any existing accounts to these new accounts as soon as you are in a place to do so. (Rushing does not help, doing it safely is the most important thing.)

  - [Get a](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-create-a-new-wallet) [Ledger or Trezor Hardware Wallet](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/hardware-wallet-recommends) (safest!)
  - [How to Create a Cold Storage Wallet](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-safely-slash-offline-slash-cold-storage-with-myetherwallet) (still really safe!)
  - [How to Create a New Wallet](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-create-a-new-wallet)
- Never enter your private keys, passwords, sensitive data on a website that you were sent via message
- ONLY unlock your wallet when you want to send a transaction. Check your balance via https://etherscan.io/ or https://ethplorer.io/
- Do not trust messages or addresses or URLs sent via private message. Always verify information w/ a secondary source.
- [Install the MyEtherWallet Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myetherwallet-cx/nlbmnnijcnlegkjjpcfjclmcfggfefdm) AND....
- **Read our guide on [How to Prevent Loss & Theft](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/protecting-yourself-and-your-funds)**

#### Again, I'm very sorry to hear this happened to you. Please let me know if any of the above is unclear or you can use any more assistance.